# getting error while excuting update method in spring boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot

I am developing a rest api and  i want to make and update end point . but when i try to excute it i get error . but I can excute the query on datbase without any problems.

repositoty

@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true ,value = "UPDATE CAR c  SET c.PERSON_ID =:PERSON_ID WHERE ID=:ID")
void updatecarOner(Long PERSON_ID,Long ID);

controller

```
  @PutMapping("person/car/{ID}")
    public  void updateCarOwner(@PathVariable Long ID,@RequestParam Long PERSON_ID){

        repository.updatecarOner(PERSON_ID,ID);

    }
```

entity class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="Brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name="ModelName")
    private String modelname;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name="RegisterDate")
    private Date registerdate;

    @Column(name="LicensePlateNumber")
    private String LicensePlateNumber ;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "personId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="Person_id_fk"))

    private person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "addressid", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name ="adress_id_fk"))

    private address address;


}
```

my error is

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1692) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar:5.6.8.Final]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:241) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]